# How do I insert multiple records?

Tags: database, joomla-4.x, fields, pivot, batch

First, I took user_id, name, and email for the `#__users` table and joined with custom `#__field_values` `lot`, `address`, and `phone`.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('u.id, u.name, u.email')
    ->select("(SELECT fv.value FROM #__fields_values AS fv INNER JOIN #__fields AS f ON f.id = fv.field_id WHERE u.id = fv.item_id AND 'lot' = f.name) AS lot")
    ->select("(SELECT fv.value FROM #__fields_values AS fv INNER JOIN #__fields AS f ON f.id = fv.field_id WHERE u.id = fv.item_id AND 'address' = f.name) AS address")
    ->select("(SELECT fv.value FROM #__fields_values AS fv INNER JOIN #__fields AS f ON f.id = fv.field_id WHERE u.id = fv.item_id AND 'phone' = f.name) AS phone")
    ->from('#__users AS u')
    ->order('lot ASC');
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadAssocList();

print_r($rows);
```

`print_r($rows)` look like this:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [0] => 73
    [1] => Groucho Marx
    [2] => groucho@mail.com
    [3] => 001
    [4] => 123 Maple Street
    [5] => 555-555-1111
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [0] => 74
    [1] => Chico Marx
    [2] => chico@gmail.com
    [3] => 002
    [4] => 456 Elm Street
    [5] => 555-555-2222
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [0] => 75
    [1] => Harpo Marx
    [2] => harpo@mac.com
    [3] => 003
    [4] => 789 Oak Street
    [5] => 555-555-3333
  )
  ...and so on...
```

Now I want to insert the records into #__users_directory. I tried this but nothing happened. No error, just an empty table.

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$columns = array('id', 'name', 'email', 'lot', 'address', 'phone');
$values = array($db->quote($rows['id']),$db->quote($rows['name']),$db->quote($rows['email']),$db->quote($rows['lot']),$db->quote($rows['address']),$db->quote($rows['phone']));
$query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__users_directory'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
    ->values(implode(',',$values));
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

Part two of my question is how to build a foreach loop to insert multiple records at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print_r($rows)` result of your 1st `select` query looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 413
            [name] => John Doe
            [email] => john@example.com
            [lot] => 
            [address] => Elm street
            [phone] => 555-1234 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 414
            [name] => Jane Doe
            [email] => jane@example.com
            [lot] => 
            [address] => 99 main street
            [phone] => 555-5678
        )
)
```

I would try the following:

```
$columns = array('id', 'name', 'email', 'lot', 'address', 'phone');

foreach($rows as $row)
{
  $values = [$row['id'], $db->quote($row['name']), $db->quote($row['email']),
  $db->quote($row['lot']),$db->quote($row['address']), $db->quote($row['phone'])];

  $query = $db->getQuery(true)
   ->insert($db->quoteName('#__users_directory'))
   ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
   ->values(implode(',',$values));

  // Display your query to test in phpMyAdmin.
  echo "<pre>";
  echo $query->dump();
  echo "</pre>";
  // Remove this part from your final code.

  $db->setQuery($query);
  $db->execute();
}
```

Though maybe there's a more efficient way to do this...